# Change word after quotation in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I know you can use `cw` to change the word and `ciw` to change the inner word, but what i'm trying to do is change the word after the character.

For example I have this

```
this.option('test');
```

Now my cursor is at the first quote (') and I want to change the word test. If I press `cw` it also deletes the first quote my cursor is on. I'm on the other hand looking for a command that imitates the `a` mode (where it inserts after the cursor), so in my case deletes the word after cursor and puts it in insert mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cw` is not "change the word", it's *"change to next word"*.

With the cursor on either of the single quotes, you can use `ci'` to "change between single quotes".

With the cursor on the first single quote, you could also do:

```
wciw          move to next word then change inner word
wcw           move to next word then change to next word
wct'          move to next word then change until next single quote
wce           move to next word then change to end of the word

lciw          move to next character then change inner word
lcw           move to next character then change to next word
lct'          move to next character then change until next single quote
lce           move to next word then change to end of the word

<Right>ciw    move to next character then change inner word
<Right>cw     move to next character then change to next word
<Right>ct'    move to next character then change until next single quote
<Right>ce     move to next word then change to end of the word
```

See `:help navigation`.

Comment: thanks for the correction and the `ci'` command. this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If your cursor is at ( **'** ) than you can use

```
ci'
```

This will delete the **text** and sets you in insert mode to make the change.

So it's change inside the **'**.